# Trying to use jOrgChart dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am hoping to use jOrgChart (link: [jOrgChart](http://th3silverlining.com/2011/12/01/jquery-org-chart-a-plugin-for-visualising-data-in-a-tree-like-structure/)) for the user to dynamically create a tree algorithm. I am running into many problems as expected (this being my first time using a tree plug-in) but the first and foremost is that I cant get a ".add_child" input button to add another 'li' to, well, anything...

I hope someone can spot what I am doing wrong.

[here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VGVG/2/)

I wrote this in at the bottom of the plug-in in order to show it all in one javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#org').jOrgChart();
    $('.add_child').live({
        click: function() {
            var $new_child = '<li>test1</li>';

        }
    });
});
```

Note: I also added this at the very end of the plug-in to make it so the "+" button wouldn't collapse the tree:

```
$nodeDiv.children('input{class=\"add_child\"').click(function(e){
        console.log(e);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fork, it has the ability to add/remove nodes https://github.com/vellonce/jOrgChart